# Compute the double geometric series $\sum_{(i,j)\in L}\frac{1}{18}\bigl(\frac{5}{6}\bigr)^i\bigl(\frac{2}{4}\bigr)^j$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> I would like to compute the following series : $\sum_{(i,j)\in L}u_{i,j}$ where 
>   $$
> u_{i,j}=\frac{1}{18}\bigl(\frac{5}{6}\bigr)^i\bigl(\frac{2}{4}\bigr)^j \quad \text{and}\quad L=\{(i,j)\in\Bbb{N^2}; 0\le i\le j\}.
> $$

I am stuck, I don't follow how can I compute with the condition in $L$. If we are $(i,j)\Bbb\in{N^2}$ without any condition I can compute the sums which is equal to $1$.

Comment: I'm bit really sure, but what if you think about a double sum. With $ j \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ i \leq j$. So the sum that involves $i$ depends on $j$ but $j$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{18}\sum_{0\le i\le j}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^i\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^j=
\frac{1}{18}\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left(
1+\frac{5}{6}+\cdots+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^j
\right)
\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^j
=\frac{1}{18}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty
\frac{1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{j+1}}{1-\frac{5}{6}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^j\\
=\frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^j-\frac{5}{6}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\frac{5}{12}\right)^j\right)=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{5}{18}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{5}{12}}=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{10}{21}=\frac{12}{63}.
$$

Comment: I agree with everything up to the very last equality,  but $2/3-10/21$ is not $11/63$.

Comment: @WillO: Thanks.